# Check if value exist in SQLite. If it exists, alert the user that the value exists

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I've created a table in `SQLite`, and I want to check if the value exist before the user can add that value to the table. Please, check my code below:

```
//check if value exists

Cursor checkIfExist = shoppingListDB.rawQuery("SELECT *    FROM "+ selected_spinner + " WHERE " + "ITEM_NAME  = " + "'" + add_tems + "'", null);

if (checkIfExist == null) {
    String insert_data="INSERT INTO " +   selected_spinner + " (ITEM_NAME,SHOP_LIST,NUMB_ITEMS) VALUES " + "('" + add_tems + "'," + "'" + add_shop + "'," + "'" + add_quantity + "'" + ")";
    shoppingListDB.execSQL(insert_data);
} else 
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " " + add_tems + " Exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: what is your problem ?

Comment: When i enter new item, it says the item it execute the else clause even if the value doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The else clause is executed because the Cursor object will never be null. The rawQuery() always returns a Cursor object.
So you need to test if the sql query affected one or more rows or not:

```
if(checkIfExist.moveToFirst()){
    //value exist
}else{
    //value does not exist
}
```

moveToFirst() returns false if the Cursor is empty([doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst%28%29))

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

```
Cursor checkIfExist = shoppingListDB.rawQuery("SELECT *    FROM "+ selected_spinner + " WHERE " + "ITEM_NAME  = " + "'" + add_tems + "'", null);

checkIfExist.moveToFirst(); 

        if ( checkIfExist.getCount() > 0 ) 
        {
            String insert_data="INSERT INTO " +   selected_spinner + " (ITEM_NAME,SHOP_LIST,NUMB_ITEMS) VALUES " + "('" + add_tems + "'," + "'" + add_shop + "'," + "'" + add_quantity + "'" + ")";
            shoppingListDB.execSQL(insert_data);

        } 
        else 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " " + add_tems + " Exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks but,Still executing the else clause even if the value is new

Comment: @LetmeSuckitBaby, do one thing, remove your application and test with a fresh one.

Comment: @LetmeSuckitBaby that's strange, what's value in your table ?

Comment: android.database.sqlite SQLiteCursor@42c46390

Comment: I mean the value that is there in table. What is it ?

Comment: when i toast it it show android.database.sqlite SQLiteCursor@42c46390

Comment: if i enter bananas as a new value it says the bananas exist and when i toast the value of add_items it shows android.database.sqlite SQLiteCursor@42c46390

Comment: @LetmeSuckitBaby but somehow you must be entering value in `add_items` variable right , otherwise how can it take value like `SQLiteCursor@42c46390` ?

Comment: I don't know what to do.

Comment: @LetmeSuckitBaby, I am asking you that how are you setting value in `add_items` variable ? Have you wrote a code like add_items = "abcsdfd"; somewere in your code ?

Comment: here is the code String add_tems = addItemsToList.getText().toString();

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of implementation. You could change your method to return a `List` with all the objects from the `Database`

Something like:

```
public List<Item> getAllItems() {
    List<Item> items = new LinkedList<Item>();

    // 1. build the query
    String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + selected_spinner;

    // 2. get reference to writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    // 3. go over each row, build item and add it to list
    Item item = null;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            item = new Item ((cursor.getString(1)), cursor.getString(2));
            item .setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            // Add item to items
            items.add(item);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    Log.d("getAllItems()", items.toString());

    // return items
    return items;
}
```

Then, you could call that method:

```
boolean valueExist = false;

private List<String> nameOfItems = new ArrayList<String>();

private static List<Item> itemList = null;

DataBaseHelper db = new DataBaseHelper(this);

itemList = db.getAllItems();

db.close();

if(itemList .size() != 0){
    for(Item i : itemList ){
        nameOfItems .add(i.getName());
    }
}
```

And finally check if the value exist...

```
if(nameOfItems.contains(//Any String that you might want to check){
    valueExist = true;
}
```